# AppStore credit card authorization fail

Tags: itunes, apple-id, itunes-store

I purchased an app 5 days ago and the the amount was debited in my account but my purchase history shows

> We were unable to authorize your credit card for this purchase. Please update your billing info.

What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Update your billing info? :-)

- https://reportaproblem.apple.com/

Usually this happens if the credit card check fails. To fix, log into your account in iTunes and either update the credit card details or add a new one:

- open iTunes
- go to the iTunes store (<kbd>Shift-Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>)
- click on your Apple ID at top left and select "Account"
- Billing info should be the second line in the overview, select "Edit" at the right